# compiling perl as 64 bit on solaris 10 sparc

Tags: c, perl, gcc, 64-bit, solaris

I am trying to compile `perl 5.22.2` on `Solaris`, sparc, as 64 bit (os is 64 bit). 
It compiled and linked fine as a 32 bit binary, now I have added the `-m64` flag to `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, and I am getting the following error:

```
...skipping...
perlio.c:3400: error: structure has no member named `_ptr'
perlio.c:3408: error: structure has no member named `_ptr'
perlio.c: In function `PerlIOStdio_get_base':
perlio.c:3531: error: structure has no member named `_base'
perlio.c: In function `PerlIOStdio_get_bufsiz':
perlio.c:3538: error: structure has no member named `_cnt'
perlio.c:3538: error: structure has no member named `_ptr'
perlio.c:3538: error: structure has no member named `_base'
perlio.c: In function `PerlIOStdio_get_ptr':
perlio.c:3547: error: structure has no member named `_ptr'
perlio.c: In function `PerlIOStdio_get_cnt':
perlio.c:3554: error: structure has no member named `_cnt'
perlio.c: In function `PerlIOStdio_set_ptrcnt':
perlio.c:3575: error: structure has no member named `_ptr'
perlio.c:3594: error: structure has no member named `_cnt'
make: *** [perlio.o] Error 1
```

For reference, i have extracted the mentioned lines from `perlio.c`:

```
3400:   STDCHAR *eptr = (STDCHAR*)PerlSIO_get_ptr(s);
3408:       if ((STDCHAR*)PerlSIO_get_ptr(s) != --eptr || ((*eptr & 0xFF) != ch)) {
3531:    return (STDCHAR*)PerlSIO_get_base(stdio);
3538:    return PerlSIO_get_bufsiz(stdio);
3547:    return (STDCHAR*)PerlSIO_get_ptr(stdio);
3554:    return PerlSIO_get_cnt(stdio);
3575:   PerlSIO_set_ptr(stdio, ptr); /* LHS STDCHAR* cast non-portable */
3594:    PerlSIO_set_cnt(stdio, cnt);
```

It looks like its doing something strange with the source, notice how `_ptr` is treated as a seperate entity, whereas the function is called `PerlSIO_get_ptr`. Looks like its being cut off.

Anyone any idea what is going on here? FYI using something like perlbrew is not an option, I need to compile this myself :(.

Comment: Did you rerun your configuration to fully detect 64-bit options?  It looks like you tried to just change the compile flags using the same source directory that was already configured for a 32-bit build.

Comment: Yes, I have freshly unpacked the source befor configuring and building. However my build scripts are a bit convoluted, so I will double check there is nothing funky going on. Will report back later.

Comment: You need to ensure the compilations done during the configuration stage are also done with `-m64`.  Look through your configuration output.  If you see things like `sizeof(long) = 4`, the configuration was done with 32-bit compiles, which will produce incorrect results.  Because the 32-bit `FILE` structure on Solaris does have `_ptr` and `_cnt` members, while the 64-bit `FILE` structure is totally opaque.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewHenle - I think you actually nailed it. It was indeed a missing configure flag that caused the error. See my answer below. You helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add the `-Duse64bitall` flag to the `Configure` script. So finally I was able to build with

```
export CFLAGS=-m64 # not sure if really nessessary - just what I did
./Configure -Duse64bitall -Dcc=gcc -d
make
```

For my setup I also need some more libraries, so this is a rather simplified version. However it solved the problem described in this post.